# Number of ways to form groups of balls

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I have $12$ balls, $6$ are white and $6$ are black. I want to make four groups of balls. Each group contains three balls. How many arrangements are possible? Assuming all the same colored balls are identical.

**Thoughts:** If all the balls would have been different the problem would have become simpler. I can arrange the balls in $12!$ ways and can argue that for each possible arrangement I can pick 3 balls at a time from the arranged sequence and form a group. I think a similar approach should work in identical balls case too. Giving the total number of ways as $\dfrac{12!}{6!6!}$. I don't know the answer to this problem. It will be really helpful if we can verify the answer with different methods.

Comment: Do you want to distiguish among the groups? E.g., are "$3$ black, $3$ black, $3$ white, $3$ white" and "$3$ white, $3$ white, $3$ black, $3$ black" different arrangements?

Comment: I suppose that does not count as different, as the question is about different forms to group in sets of 3 balls.

Comment: @joriki sorry for the ambiguity. As Alejandro has rightly figured out they don't count as different groups.

Comment: Well, looks like you got an answer for both versions :-)

Comment: Yes, thanks to the ambiguity. Is manually counting the only option for indistinguishable groups? Also @joriki can you please point out the mistake in my approach? What am I recounting?

Comment: Now I'm confused – why did you accept the answer that assumed that you distinguish among the groups?

Comment: Actually I accepted that answer because it uses an elegant way to solve which works for larger numbers. I then thought that indistinguishable groups case is hard and requires manual counting. Both answers are equally good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $6$ white balls (and therefore $6$ black balls) to place into $4$ bags. Each bag can contain $0,1,2$ or $3$ white balls (and correspondingly has $3-k$ black balls).

After each ball has been placed, we have a representative of the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^4$.

So finding the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^4$ gives the answer.

This can be calculated as:

$$[x^6]\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^4$$

$$=[x^6]\frac{1-4x^4+\dots}{(1-x)^4}$$

$$=[x^6]\left(1-4x^4+\dots\right)\left(\sum_\limits{k=3}^\infty \binom{k}{3} x^{k-3}\right)$$

$$=\binom{9}{3}-4\binom{5}{3}$$

$$=84-4\cdot10$$

$$=44$$

Comment: Can you please add an explanation for the first statement you made?

Comment: +1, elegant method.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $4$ bins as groups. This problem is equivalent to calculating the number of partitions of $6$ comprising no more than $4$ numbers, with each group having 3 balls, after which the other- colored balls will fill the gap in each bin. You can manually count the partitions:

$3,0,0,3$,

$1,2,0,3$,

$1,1,1,3$:

$1,2,1,2$

$2,2,2,0$

That’s $5$ ways. Note that this is assuming the groups are not distinguishable.

Comment: What about $2,2,2,0$? Anf the groups only have $3$ balls in them.

Comment: @JMP Thank you, corrected.

Comment: Can you please add methods for counting for larger values?

Comment: @Shiv Tavker I’m not so sure, but maybe you could work with this recursion: $$f(w,b,g) = \frac 1g \sum_{k=0}^{\frac ng} f(w-\frac ng +k, b-k, g-1)$$ where $w,b,g$ are the number of white balls, black balls and the groups they are to be sorted into respectively.

Comment: @Tavish thanks this makes sense